# xamarin.auth stuck on success when isUsingNativeUI true

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

Im using xamarin.auth for facebook, google and twitter login. Its not closing browser after get success, if i close browser manually IsAuthenticated returning false. If i use isUsingNativeUI false it works fine but very ugly new page with uncontrolled color and title. Is where a way to change color and title on there? I can use these 2 ways too but need to fix.

```
                var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId,                    
                Constants.FacebookScope,
                new Uri(Constants.FacebookAuthorizeUrl),
                new Uri(Constants.FacebookAccessTokenUrl),
                null, isUsingNativeUI: true);

            authenticator.Completed += OnAuthCompleted;
            authenticator.Error += OnAuthError;

            AuthenticationState.Authenticator = authenticator;

            var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
            presenter.Login(authenticator);
```

[image]

Ugly navigation bar and title

[image: Ugly nav bar]

Comment: Was the redirect schema called on isUsingNativeUI = true?

Comment: On first screenshot yes.

Comment: Support for Xamarin.Auth has stopped long ago, you could you the latest [Social Auth introduced in Xamarin.Essentials](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/authentication-xamarin-essentials-aspnet/)

Comment: @ErroCode-112MonkeyFound i just get what you mean, but can you explain how to add it on redirect uri?

Comment: Make sure that the emulator had installed Chrome . Otherwise it will open with WebView , which will maybe cause the error .

Comment: Yes, chorme installed.

Comment: I can use redirect schema on google login but facebook. Someone can help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my issue with correct redirect url. 111111 means your client Id, add fb on start, ://authorize to the end of it.

```
        public static string FacebookiOSRedirectUrl = "fb1111111111111://authorize";
        public static string FacebookAndroidRedirectUrl = "fb1111111111111://authorize";
```

On ios it say unknown or wrong redirect url, you can fix it with add this on your plist.

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>     
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>Xamarin.Auth facebook PAuth</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb111111111111</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```